# Better way to pass an object to multiple inherited classes

Tags: python, class, inheritance, parameters

I want to know if there is a more efficient way to pass an argument to the parent class that all child classes can use. Here's an example where myVar needs to be passed to all child classes of a. (only child class is b in the example). I want to know if there's a way to do this without requiring all child classes to pass in myVar as an argument, where myVar is always the same object. Maybe there is a design pattern for a more efficient system? Thanks.

```
class a(object):
    def __init__(self, myVar):
        self.myVar = myVar

class b(a):
    def __init__(self, myVar):
        super(b, self).__init__(myVar)

class c(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        print a.myVar

a = b(2)
d = c(a)
```

Comment: is myVar constant?

Comment: @Verbal_Kint It is essentially constant. It is always the same object.

Comment: Then a class variable is the way to go as shown in @George's answer, except the a.myVar is odd, do you mean to pass a class as an argument or inherit from it to access the variable?

Comment: Did you intend to *destroy* your first class definition with this assignment `a = b(2)`?

Comment: If possible, you should switch to Python 3.6+ ... https://pythonclock.org/

Comment: @Verbal_Kint Just inherit from it. Sorry, I'm using very confusing names, that's my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways that you could do this, depending on exactly what it is you're trying to do.
If you don't define an `__init__` methd for your class it will automatically inherit the `__init__` method of the parent class. E.g.:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, my_var):
        self.my_var = my_var

class B(A):
    pass

class c(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        print(a.my_var)

a = B(2)
d = C(a)
```

If you don't want to share an `__init__` method you could always try defining a default value on the parent class.

```
class A(object):

    DEFAULT_VALUE = 42

    def __init__(self, my_var=None):    
        self.my_var = my_var or self.DEFAULT_VALUE

class B(A):
    def __init__(foo, my_var=None):
        super(B, self).__init__(foo, my_var)

class c(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        print(a.my_var)

a = B(2)
d = C(a)
```

Or, with a global variable. Caveat emptor.

```
MY_VAR = None


class A(object):

    def __init__(self, my_var=None):
        global MY_VAR
        if MY_VAR is None:
            MY_VAR = my_var
        elif my_var and MY_VAR != my_var:
            print("WARNING: Value of {my_var} for `my_var` being ignored")
        else:
            pass

        self.my_var = MY_VAR


class B(A):

    def __init__(self, foo, my_var=None):
        super(B, self).__init__(my_var)
        self._foo = foo


class C(object):

    def __init__(self, a):
        print(a.my_var)


a = A(42)
b = B("bar")
c = C(b)
```

Comment: I should also mention that ideally I want to know if it is possible to pass in my_var once for the parent class, then have all children classes use this without passing it in as an argument themselves. But my_var also is only evaluated at run time so I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: Oh, you could do that with a global variable, but I generally try to avoid global variables as not being worth the trouble. I'll update my answer though.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare myVar as a class variable like this:

```
class a(object):
    myVar = 2
    def __init__(self):
        ...

class b(a):
    def __init__(self):
        super(b, self).__init__()

class c(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        print(a.myVar)

a = b()
d = c(a)
```

Comment: `a = b()` - did you just assign something different to a class name?

Comment: You right. In this case i just assign the same class. Class a in this case is abstract and it store only a myVar class variable.

Comment: My idea was, that if myVar is a constant for class a, we need to declare it as a class variable, not to parse it to each child class.

Comment: @wwii Sorry, imagine it's g = b(). I realise that I gave the object the same name as the class so it's a little confusing.

Comment: Except that the OP didn't say the value is constant for the class. The said it's constant for the object.

Comment: I am sorry that my idea was so confusing. @Batman posted better version of my idea.